# What is the idiomatic strategy for creating docker container in a build system

Tags: docker, build, cmake

I've a somewhat complex project - about a dozen of micro services, a little bit more libraries (shared objects or static), some static folders with html resources. The project has C++ and Python components. The project is ultimately shipped as Docker's images, which are pushed to docker hub as part of the build process.

I'm using cmake to do it all.

I wonder if the community have developed an idiomatic strategy for building the images. In terms of makefile, I'm doing something like:

```
main_executable: a.cpp b.cpp
    gcc ...


docker_image: main_executable Dockerfile ... other stuff that gets into the containers
    docker build --tag my_image --file Dockerfile .
```

main_executable is a real file, and dependency check is working great. However, docker_image is a phony target. It represents a docker image somewhere in docker land. As a phony target is is always "out of date", and docker build is always executed, even though the changes in the source don't affect the respective executable. Multiply by dozens of images, it is very time consuming, which I would like to save.

Ideally, I would like to tell make to compare the date of the docker image (maybe with 'docker image inspect') with the dependencies.

I'll be surprised if I'm the first person with this issue. What is your strategy? I'm happy with cmake, but familiar with bunch of others (gradle, Scons, maven) and would switch if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safe and efficient to blindly re-run `docker build` as you show.  Because of Docker's [image caching](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache), even if it has to run through all of the steps of the Dockerfile, Docker is able to detect that none of the inputs have changed (including that the `main_executable` is the same file as before) and will skip all of the work, producing an identical image output.

If you still want to skip the rebuild, it's reasonably idiomatic to have the build process generate a real file.  (The [GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Empty-Targets.html#Empty-Targets) has an example in a different context.)  This approach works better if you can exhaustively list out all of the files that go into the image build (but this is possible especially if the image mostly consists of a compiled binary).

```makefile
main_executable: a.cpp b.cpp
        gcc -o $@ ...

# This is a phony convenience target
docker_image: .build.docker

# This is a real file, on success we touch it to update its timestamp
.build.docker: main_executable Dockerfile ...
        docker build --tag my_image --file Dockerfile .
        touch $@

clean:
        rm -f main_executable .build.docker

.PHONY: docker_image clean
```